# Ninject Kernel.Get<T> Instance Creation

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

Today I discovered a bug in my code base, where an injected dependency was supposedly out living the class it was being injected into. When I expected a new instance of the dependency to always be injected, i was getting an old one. I managed to clean up the bug by removing the line `this.Kernel.Get<IA>()` from the simplified snippet below. While this isn't the complete picture of the project, it is the exact configuration used for the perpetrator.

```
internal sealed class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IA>().To<A>();

        this.Bind<B>().ToSelf()
            .WithConstructorArgument(this.Kernel.Get<IDependencyOne>())
            .WithConstructorArgument(this.Kernel.Get<IDependencyTwo>())
            .WithConstructorArgument(this.Kernel.Get<IA>())
            .WithConstructorArgument<uint>(50U);
    }
```

So while I would always get a new instance of `B` I would get an old instance of `IA`. Could anyone help me understand the lifecycle for the `.Get<T>` extension method from `IResolutionRoot`? I always assumed that a call to `.Get<T>` would generate an instance according to the previous configuration as set out by  my bindings. Is this correct behavior for Ninject?

#### Information

- Using Ninject 3.2.2.0
- C# 5, .Net 4.5 Framework
- WPF Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try passing a lambda expression to .WithConstructorArgument()

```
this.Bind<B>().ToSelf()
        .WithConstructorArgument(() => this.Kernel.Get<IDependencyOne>())
        .WithConstructorArgument(() => this.Kernel.Get<IDependencyTwo>())
        .WithConstructorArgument(() => this.Kernel.Get<IA>())
        .WithConstructorArgument<uint>(50U);
```

I think your code gets IA at the beginning and then always passes it to the constructor of B when it's retrieved. Lambda method on the other hand should be called every time B is constructed.

Alternatively, you could try only specifying the named `uint` variable in the module:

```
this.Bind<B>().ToSelf()
        .WithConstructorArgument<uint>("uintParamName", 50U);
```

Ninject should resolve the remaining arguments as long as there's a binding for them.

Comment: I cannot try this until tomorrow, but yes ofcourse! I completely overlooked the lack of a lambda in my code. That would make perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: Very good answer, especially also the part about the most argument specifications being superfluous! There's no need to use `.WithConstructorArgument()` for stuff one want's injected by the container. That works out of the box!